# How to call excel function and send parameters

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to call the access function and send parameters from excel
there is my access function

```
{
Function Macro1(source As String)

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, "Table1", source, True, ""

End Function
}
```

How to call this function?

Comment: `Range("A1") = Macro1("YourString")`

Comment: can you explain it in more details.